# How many objects are created?

Tags: java, object, memory, heap-memory

Do we have `6` boolean objects in this case?

```
Boolean b1 = true;
Boolean b2 = true;
Boolean b3 = true;
Boolean b4 = new Boolean(true);
Boolean b5 = new Boolean(true);
Boolean b6 = new Boolean(true);
```

Comment: No, there's only 3 new objects created in that code. If you count the existing `Boolean.TRUE`, there's 4 objects.

Comment: `Boolean b1 = true;` compiles as `Boolean b1 = Boolean.valueOf(true);` and `Boolean.valueOf(true)` returns `Boolean.TRUE`, so the effect is that `Boolean b1 = true;` is the same as `Boolean b1 = Boolean.TRUE;`, which means that your code is creating **3 objects**.

Answer (score 2):

There are four distinct objects. In Oracles' Java implementation, distinct objects have distinct `IdentityHashCodes`.  So:

```
        Set<Integer> dups = Stream
                .of(b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6)
                .map(System::identityHashCode)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());

        System.out.println(dups.size()); // prints 4
```

And as a side note, the `Boolean` constructor is `deprecated`.

Comment: Nice answer! +1 for it. Instead of collecting to a `Set`, it can also be done as `Stream.of(b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6).map(System::identityHashCode).distinct().count()`.